# Backwards-compatible solution for "rails/init.rb is deprecated"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

A Rails plugin I use ([google_analytics](https://github.com/kyusik/google_analytics)) that was written for Rails 2.3 contains a file called rails/init.rb, which under Rails 3 yields the warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Use toplevel init.rb; rails/init.rb is deprecated: /home/logankoester/hack/active/myapp/vendor/plugins/google_analytics/rails/init.rb. (called from <top (required)> at /home/logankoester/hack/active/myapp/config/environment.rb:5)
```

Now, I could simply move the file in my fork, but I don't expect this would be backwards-compatible with Rails 2. Is there a solution to this change that would work for both versions, or will I have to maintain separate branches for each major version of Rails?

Comment: Try to rewrite it to a gem and bundle it. That would work for Rails 2 as well.

Comment: @Ariejan this should be an answer, I would vote it up...

Comment: @Fàbio Batista - There you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rewrite it to a gem and bundle it. That would work for Rails 2 as well.